# Writing a function for custom subcommands discord.py

Tags: python, command, bots, discord.py

So, I want to write a function for all subcommands for my python bot but I'm not sure how they work in discord.py. For instance, I have this mute code here.

```
@bot.command()
async def mute(ctx,member : discord.Member, *, reason=None):

    with open("role.json", "r") as f:
        roles = json.load(f)

    muted_role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, id=roles[f"{ctx.guild.id}"]["role_id"])
  
    embed = discord.Embed(color=discord.Color(0xFF0000), title=f"{member} has been muted.")
            #sent to DM
    embedC=discord.Embed(title=f"{member} has been muted.",color=discord.Color(0xff0000))
    embedC.add_field(name=f"Member",value=f"{member}",inline=False)
    embedC.add_field(name=f"Moderator",value=f"{ctx.author}",inline=False)
    embedC.add_field(name=f"Reason",value=f"{reason}",inline=False)
    embedC.set_footer(text=f"Mute was successfully invoked. Expiration is indefinite.")
    await member.add_roles(muted_role)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    await member.send(embed=embedC)
```

In the code above is my `mute` command. I know this is a bit irrelevant to my question but I want to make a custom subcommand for bot. You can remove built in command `help` by doing bot `bot.remove_command("help")` but how do I remove custom help  subcommand? Now this leads to the second part of the question, which is also the main question. How do I write a function for custom subcommand so I won't have to write and repeat the same process over for every subcommand?
I tried doing `def subcommand(command, error)` where the command is the command needed for help and error is the error message I want to put. So in case my mute command fails, it will ask user to use my subcommand and my subcommand will provide them with information on how this command works. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There's an built-in subcommand support:

```py
@bot.group()
async def cmd(ctx):
    if ctx.invoked_subcommand is None:
        await ctx.send("Command can't be invoked without a subcommand")


@cmd.command()
async def subcommand1(ctx, *args):
    #...


@cmd.command()
async def subcommand2(ctx, *args):
    #...
```

To invoke:

```
{prefix}cmd subcommand1 arg1 arg2
```

[Docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html?highlight=subcommand#how-do-i-make-a-subcommand)